# header search path in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I want to add a path to the header search path. However in the build settings when I double click on the header search path.. it doesn't pop up a new window where I can type.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Click on the project in the file navigator on the left.  Then click on the project or target in the editor that appears.  Click on "Build Settings", then change from "Basic" to "All".  Its under search paths.

Comment: that is no longer the solution under xcode 4.4.1 - apple please fix this - make history of search strings available as some picklist - major FAIL

Comment: @EventHorizon: Not sure about 4.4.1, but 'Search Paths' is there under 4.5, so long as you change the view from "Basic" to "All".

Comment: I have been using all flavors of 4 - currently on 4.5. The problem I am having is I can slow double-click and edit inline, or I can double-click and a popup is displayed. I can edit paths, add paths, set recursive. Problem is, there is no way to exit the popup except for escape (cancel). If I drag it, the popup becomes a dialog, but still no controls for "OK" Sometimes I can get the settings to take if I select "Validate Settings", but not always. How can I exit that window with "OK"?