# How to get HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS to produce -isystem includes in XCode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, include, clang

I want to suppress warnings in the headers we include from third party libraries.  According to what I've read here and elsewhere (e.g., [Set system search path in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322564/set-system-search-path-in-xcode-4)), by putting the appropriate path in the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS variable of the .pbxproj file, it should result in clang using a -isystem command line option instead of -I, thus suppressing warnings.

However, it's not working.  As you can see from the snippet of the .pbx file below, we're setting the include paths using that variable, but the clang command is using -I.  Is there something else I need to be doing to get it to work?

Compile line generated:

```
   CompileC /Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/Objects-normal/i386/Register.o legacy/Client/Library/LibEngine/Register.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/stebro/daemon
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
     -x c++
     -arch i386
     -fmessage-length=0
     -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack
     -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0
     -Wno-trigraphs
     -fpascal-strings
     -O0
     -Wno-missing-field-initializers
     -Wno-missing-prototypes
     -Wno-return-type
     -Wno-non-virtual-dtor
     -Wno-overloaded-virtual
     -Wno-exit-time-destructors
     -Wno-missing-braces
     -Wparentheses
     -Wswitch
     -Wno-unused-function
     -Wno-unused-label
     -Wno-unused-parameter
     -Wno-unused-variable
     -Wunused-value
     -Wno-empty-body
     -Wno-uninitialized
     -Wno-unknown-pragmas
     -Wno-shadow
     -Wno-four-char-constants
     -Wno-conversion
     -Wno-constant-conversion
     -Wno-int-conversion
     -Wno-bool-conversion
     -Wno-enum-conversion
     -Wshorten-64-to-32
     -Wno-newline-eof
     -Wno-c++11-extensions
     -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"
     -DPRODVER_STRING=\"99.9.9d1\ build\ 999\ (2008-01-01\ 12:00:00)\"
     -DPRODVER_FULL=\"99.9.999\"
     -DPRODVER_MAJOR=99
     -DPRODVER_MINOR=9
     -DPRODVER_BUILD_NO=999
     -DQT_CORE_LIB
     -DASSERT_ON
     -DQT_DEBUG
     -D_DEBUG=1
     -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
     -fasm-blocks
     -fstrict-aliasing
     -Wdeprecated-declarations
     -Winvalid-offsetof
     -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
     -g
     -Wno-sign-conversion
     -I/Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Debug/include
     -I/Volumes/ToolChain/include
     -I/Volumes/ToolChain/qt-4.8/include
     -I/Volumes/ToolChain/qt-4.8/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Library/LibEngine/../../include
     -I/Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Shared/Common/../include
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Shared/Common
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/mac/include
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/INCLUDE
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/Common
     -I/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/3rdParty/jsoncpp/include
     -I/Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/DerivedSources/i386
     -I/Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/DerivedSources
     -Wmost
     -Wno-four-char-constants
     -Wno-unknown-pragmas
     -F/Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Debug
     -F/Volumes/ToolChain/qt-4.8/lib
     -Werror
     -Wno-c++11-extensions
     -Wno-c99-extensions
     -Wno-c++98-compat
     -Wno-#warnings
     -include /var/folders/bv/5qmzyrw94_lbq7qpql9pykr4fm0g52/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Engine_pch-bsdymkkefyenxegggqlsprjbexjx/Engine_pch.h
     -MMD
     -MT dependencies
     -MF /Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/Objects-normal/i386/Register.d
     --serialize-diagnostics /Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/Objects-normal/i386/Register.dia
     -c /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Library/LibEngine/Register.cpp
     -o /Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/ClientEngine/Services.build/Debug/ClientEngine.build/Objects-normal/i386/Register.o
```

Relevant .pbxproj sections:

```
              F73E14C1508B4E9F9713949A /* Debug */ = {
                     isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
                     buildSettings = {
                            EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = lib;
                            EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = ".a";
                            GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = YES;
                            GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO;
                            GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                            GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
                            GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "/Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/HashDefines.h";
                            GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = ("'CMAKE_INTDIR=\"$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)\"'", "'PRODVER_STRING=\"99.9.9d1 build 999 (2008-01-01 12:00:00)\"'", "'PRODVER_FULL=\"99.9.999\"'", "'PRODVER_MAJOR=99'", "'PRODVER_MINOR=9'", "'PRODVER_BUILD_NO=999'", _XCODE, );
                            GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO;
                            HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = (/Volumes/ToolChain/include, /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV, /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/mac/include, /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/INCLUDE, );
                            INSTALL_PATH = "";
                            LIBRARY_STYLE = STATIC;
                            OTHER_CFLAGS = " -Werror -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-\#warnings";
                            OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS = " -Werror -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-\#warnings";
                            OTHER_LDFLAGS = "";
                            OTHER_REZFLAGS = "";
                            PRODUCT_NAME = MacMSDEV;
                            SECTORDER_FLAGS = "";
                            SYMROOT = /Users/stebro/build_xcode/daemon/MacMSDEV;
                            USE_HEADERMAP = NO;
                            WARNING_CFLAGS = ("-Wmost", "-Wno-four-char-constants", "-Wno-unknown-pragmas", );
                     };
                     name = Debug;
              };

   ...

   /* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
   18912E836D484A05B1FC59C5 /* /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = A7FC32CB884845CE8F7194D4 /* /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp */; settings = { COMPILER_FLAGS = ""; }; };

   ...

   /* Begin PBXFileReference section */
   A7FC32CB884845CE8F7194D4 /* /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = "sourcecode.cpp.cpp"; name = "Registry.cpp"; path = "legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp"; sourceTree = SOURCE_ROOT; };

   ...

              AD3E059721084BC0933AA316 /* Source Files */ = {
                     isa = PBXGroup;
                     children = (
                            A7FC32CB884845CE8F7194D4 /* /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp */,

   ...

   /* Begin PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */
              731899E5CD5D48D18C8C9C21 /* Sources */ = {
                     isa = PBXSourcesBuildPhase;
                     buildActionMask = 2147483647;
                     files = (
                            18912E836D484A05B1FC59C5 /* /Users/stebro/daemon/legacy/Client/Mac/MSDEV/AdvAPI32/Registry.cpp */,
```

Comment: I have the same problem. As a workaround, I've noticed that manually adding `-isystem <includedirs>` to e.g. the "Other C++ flags" option will override the `-I <includedirs>` flags and will thus suppress warnings in system headers. In a CMake file, this would go into `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)`

Comment: Yes, that works.  I was hoping for something a little more "surgical", in that I don't know if unconditionally including those library paths for everything (even stuff that doesn't use those libraries) is a good idea, but that's the workaround I used as well.

Comment: @KiptonBarros - that worked for me as well! I kept finding answers saying to use Header Search Paths, but that always seemed to use `-I` instead of `-isystem`.