# Problem with Three20

Tags: iphone, facebook, uitabbarcontroller, three20

I am building an iPhone app which uses Facebook iOS SDK and Three20. I have created App with UITabBarController from scratch. Facebook User sign on working on right now but when I tried to get files in Three20 I am getting an error of "Three20/Three20.h" No Such file exists. 
       SO this is what I have do so far.
1. Created my project from scratch
2. Cloned the facebook ios sdk and drag drop src folder of it into my project
3. Cloned the three20 and run the python script given on the documentation of the site. Which seemed to be working becoz I am not getting any error on terminal.
4. Now when I tried to inlude Three20.Three20.h I am getting in an error that there is no such file.

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong.

Regards,
Sumit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your "Other Linker Flags".  Make sure you have -ObjC in there.  You may want to verify that your "Header Search Paths" are correct as well.

This screen shot shows an example of the Header Search Paths

[image: Header Search Paths for Three20]

Comment: I am really new to iPhone programming.. Can you direct me how can I get to those window. I am using Xcode 4

Comment: This is from another post: Click on the project in the file navigator on the left. Then click on the project or target in the editor that appears. Click on "Build Settings", then change from "Basic" to "All". Its under search paths.  Original post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269029/header-search-path-in-xcode-4