# Xcode: How to set up a C++ Project with Libraries

Tags: c++, xcode, libraries

I am very new to C++ and have been following some tutorials online. I have downloaded the libraries and .h files they use and included them in my file structure.

However I get this error:

'Apple Mach-0 Linker (id) Error...'

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Could you paste the whole log ?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
  "GetInteger()", referenced from:
      Main() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to:

Open Xcode. Go to:

`File -> New -> Project -> Mac OS X -> Application -> Command Line Tool`

Specify project name and set type to `C++`

To add libraries you have to specify the header search paths and path to .a files. It can be done in project build settings

You might want to take a look here: [header search path in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269029/header-search-path-in-xcode-4)

Comment: OK but how do I add other libraries