# Header file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have a project, which has a static library with references to header files like this:

```
#import <libetpan/libetpan.h>
```

I can't change this import line. What should I do, to make Xcode find those header files? I have a folder with header files, that I can import to the project. Thanks.

At the moment the error is following:

```
'libetpan/libetpan.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have added the libetpan folder to your project (if not, do so)

right click on that folder and see the path (get info after right click)

if its not a sibling of your project file in the folder structure (check in finder), thats where its going wrong

alternately, you could add header search paths: [header search path in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269029/header-search-path-in-xcode-4)

Comment: I have done this to make it working. I created a folder of this structure : Libetpan/libetpan/libetpan.h. All header files were inside Libetpan/libetpan. Then I put this folder Libetpan to the project next  to my *.xcodeproj file. Then I added this "./Libetpan" to the Build Settings of my Target in Header Search Paths.