# Lexical or preprocessor Issue: while using flite1.4-iphone library for TTS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, text-to-speech

I'm using

> flite1.4-iphone

in my application for text to speech. I'm following this link- [see here](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/)

but i get the error

> Lexical or preprocessor Issue: flite.h not found

Yes i searched google for this and apply all the solutions that i found like- close Xcode and reopen, clean project etc etc, but still cant found solution.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot find `flite.h`; looking at sfoster/iPhone TTS, it seems the file is supplied in the `flite-1.4-iphone/include/` directory.

To make the compiler find the file, add the directory where `flite.h` is in (e.g., `$(SRCROOT)/flite-1.4-iphone/include/` to the project's Header Search Paths. (see [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269029/header-search-path-in-xcode-4) for details on how to modify the path).

Comment: I've done the thing as you explained but now i'm geting the error-Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_cst_wave_save_riff", referenced from:
      -[FliteTTS speakText:] in FliteTTS.o
  "_delete_wave", referenced from:
      -[FliteTTS speakText:] in FliteTTS.o
  "_feat_set_float", referenced from:
      -[FliteTTS setPitch:variance:speed:] in FliteTTS.o
  (total 7 errors)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Any Idea?

Comment: Have you added the `.m` files to your project and target? When dragging the files into Xcode, the dialog that appears asks you what targets the files should be added to; select your project. Also, Google "Undefined symbols for architecture errors" to learn more about this error.