# Argument list too long Error

Tags: xcode, ios6

I'm working on to create new app on xcode.

I got that error

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Office First Run/MUD/Outlook Script Menu Items/Create Note from Message.scptd/Contents/Resources/Scripts.

Have any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

What's in your Header Search Paths? Looks like you let the compiler search for your headers on the whole disk recursively (`/**`).

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FastPdfKit/FastPdfKit.h>

Comment: Please search before asking... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269029/header-search-path-in-xcode-4

Comment: There is no any Header Search Paths on the project.

Comment: @deeptrancex did you find the solution for this?