# error: unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, pch

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5) to embed Unity project in iOS project.

I got the error in the `Precompile Prefix.pch` process

> error: unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)

[image]

My `Prefix.pch` contains

```
#include "Preprocessor.h"

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

#include "UnityTrampolineConfigure.h"
#include "UnityInterface.h"

#ifndef __OBJC__
    #if USE_IL2CPP_PCH
        #include "il2cpp_precompiled_header.h"
    #endif
#endif

#ifndef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR 0
#endif

#define printf_console printf
```

**Solutions I've tried:**

I checked solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971776/argument-list-too-long-error) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226087/error-unable-to-spawn-process-argument-list-too-long-in-xcode-build).

1. Moved my project in higher hierarchy `/Users/myproject`, but still not work.
2. Delete Derived Data folder
3. Clean and build

I don't have too much knowledge in C, so I'm not sure which parts of my project should I elaborate, please comment if I need to show more details.